# How to wrap this text

Tags: html, css, flexbox, html-lists

Hi basically I have this text in html

here is is picture
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbwus.png

I want to know how to wrap that left column and create another empty line when line in right column will be splitted on the next line like in the picture.

here is html

```
 <section class="karta__table">
            <ul class="left__column">
              <li>Etiam poseure</li>
              <li>Fusce wisi</li>
              <li>Bla hola tola et</li>
              <li>Vie wisi</li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="right__column">
              <li>Nulla est</li>
              <li>2305</li>
              <li>Rerurm trada</li>
              <li>A</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
```

and here is my css

```
.karta__table{

  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  margin-top: 20px;
 
  
  }
  
  .left__column {
    
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: italic;
    text-align: right;
    flex-basis:46%;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    list-style: none;
    
    
    
  
  }

  .right__column {
    text-align: left;
    flex-basis: 41%;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
```

I tried to play with flex-basis but that doesn't work any help.

Comment: Use `<table>` ...

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the HTML markup:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <span class="left"> Etiam poseure </span>
        <span class="right">Nulla est</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="left">Fusce wisi </span>
        <span class="right">2305</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="left">Bla hola tola et </span>
        <span class="right">Rerurm trada</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="left">Vie wisi </span> <span class="right">A</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And CSS:

```
ul {
    width: 200px
}

ul li {
    display: flex;
}

ul li span {
    flex: 1;
}

ul li span.left {
    flex-basis: 50%;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: yeah goo but the problem is I cant add margin to create space between them becaouse that will fck up text align on each side

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).